# Products are displayed only in the admin area

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, wp-admin

I have a code:

```
$products_query_params = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'product_cat' => 18,
);

return new WP_Query($products_query_params);
```

I need it to get products. But it works fine only if I write it directly in function.php - function $product->have_posts() returns true in this case in admin area.

But if I try to create a shortcode and display the same thing on the front end of the site, then $product->have_posts() returns false.

I think I need to add some parameter to $products_query_params, but I don't know which one.

Comment: Is your code in a function? What is `$product`? What's your shortcode code?

Comment: @JacobPeattie in a functions.php – https://pastebin.com/awTdqXzE

This shortcode in index.php – <?php echo do_shortcode('[bags_products]'); ?>